# Defining relationships with existing database in code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an existing database with two tables: MemData and MemPhone.

MemData has the following structure

```
uidMemberId (PK, uniqueidentifier not null)
strFirstName (varchar(50), null)
strLastName (varchar(50), null)
```

MemPhone has the following structure

```
uidMemberId (uniqueidentifier not null)
strPhoneNumber (varchar(50), null)
```

There's no PK on the MemberPhoneNumber table. The two tables are joined by uidMemberId but no foreign keys have been set up in the database.

**My MemData Model looks like this:**

```
[Table("MemData")]
public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<MemberPhoneNumber> MemberPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

With the configuration map looking like this:

```
 public MemberMap()
    {

        Property(t => t.MemberId).HasColumnName("uidMemberID");
        Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("strFirstName");
        Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("strLastName");
        HasMany(x => x.MemberPhoneNumbers);
    }
```

**My MemPhone Model looks like this:**

```
[Table("MemPhone")]
public class MemberPhoneNumber
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

With the configuration map looking like this:

```
  public MemberPhoneNumberMap()
    {
        Property(t => t.MemberId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(t => t.MemberId).HasColumnName("uidMemberID");
        Property(t => t.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("strPhone");

    }
```

In my MVC app, when I call

```
Uow.Members.GetAll().Include(p => p.MemberPhoneNumbers).ToList()
```

I get the following error

```
Invalid column name 'Member_MemberId'.
```

It should be looking for MemData_uidMemberId instead but I can't figure out what I've missed in the configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default foreign key name will be *propertyName* _ *entityId*. That's why EF tries to map to Member_MemberId column. Provide foreign key configuration for one-to-many relationship

```
public class MemberMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Member>
{
    public MemberMap()
    {
        ToTable("MemData");
        HasKey(m => m.MemberId);
        Property(m => m.MemberId).HasColumnName("uidMemberID");
        Property(m => m.FirstName).HasColumnName("strFirstName");
        Property(m => m.LastName).HasColumnName("strLastName");
        HasMany(x => x.MemberPhoneNumbers)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Member)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.MemberId);
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind, that you can configure key and table with fluent configuration, you don't need to pollute your entity with data annotations attributes.

Comment: Thanks but I'm receiving a different error message now. 
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Member_MemberPhoneNumbers_Target' in relationship 'Member_MemberPhoneNumbers'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Comment: @Mike hmm, let me think. You have MemberId as key for phone number. But what if member have several phones? I think your phones should have separate id. You can't have foreign key as pk in one to many mapping. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are correct but I have to work with the structure as-is. I didn't design the database. I don't know if what I need to do is possible in EF Code First.

Comment: @Mike you should either change multiplicity to one-to-one (instead of phones list you should have single phone), or add primary key column to phone. Then all will be fine

Comment: @Mike one-to-one mapping will look like `HasOptional(x => x.MemberPhoneNumber).WithRequired(p => p.Member).WillCascadeOnDelete();`

Comment: Well the DBA and I discussed it and he had been meaning to add a PK field to that table so we're all good. Thanks for your help!